# convert jquery to pure javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I don't want to use jquery in angular 4 but have the following jquery code I need to convert to either javascript or ideally typescript - help!

```
var pContainerHeight = $('.bird-box').height();

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (wScroll <= pContainerHeight) {
    $('.logo').css({
      'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll / 2 +'%)'
    });
    $('.back-bird').css({
      'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll / 4 +'%)'
    });
    $('.fore-bird').css({
      'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll / 40 +'%)'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: And what gave you the idea that Stackoverflow was a free code conversion service?

Comment: You're missing a closing set of braces at the end of that code.

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you need help writing an event listener? Selecting by class? Applying the CSS style? As mentioned, SO is not a code conversion/writing service. It is a place to come for help with problems with code you are trying to write. If your question was along the lines of "Im trying to convert this to vanilla js. Here is what I have tried and this is what isn't working, what have I done wrong?" It would be much better recieved.

Comment: I really don't think the downvotes were necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code slightly if there's only one element of each class, but for the general case:

```
const pContainerHeight = document.querySelector('.bird-box').clientHeight;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const wScroll = window.scrollY;
  if (wScroll <= pContainerHeight) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.logo').forEach(el =>
      el.style.transform = `translate(0px, ${wScroll/2}%)`);
    document.querySelectorAll('.back-bird').forEach(el =>
      el.style.transform = `translate(0px, ${wScroll/4}%)`);
    document.querySelectorAll('.fore-bird').forEach(el =>
      el.style.transform = `translate(0px, ${-wScroll/40}%)`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that this won't work with IE, Edge yes but not IE : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: It would probably also fail on `const` and template literals. But since OP was looking for a typescript solution, the code will most likely be compiled to ES5 if needed.